# Unable to Set Up ActionBarSherlock Library

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I created a new android project from source and when I clicked finish I ended up having 204 errors and I believe each one is describing a problem with the methods.

Also, when I try to add it as a library it doesn't show up.

So what did I do wrong?

EDIT:

---

Thanks to CommonsWare I no longer get the errors but I am still unable to add the library.

[image: Screenshot of Problems]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your compiler compliance is probably set to Java 1.5. I strongly recommend switching to Java 1.6 in general, and you definitely need it for ActionBarSherlock. In Java 1.5, you could not `@Override` a method defined on an interface -- in Java 1.6 you can.

For this individual project, go to Project > Properties > Java Compiler and adjust the "Compiler Compliance Level".

Comment: Thank You! Do you know how to do this for all projects?
EDIT: I found how to do it, thanks again!

Comment: @GreekOphion: Your screenshot suggests that you are trying to add ActionBarSherlock as a library for itself. That's not going to work. Go to the project you want to *use* ActionBarSherlock, go into Project > Properties > Android, and add ActionBarSherlock to that project.